# Configure AWS CLI Credentials without Secret and Access Keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have been working for the past week using Access and Secret keys that I generated for connecting REST API to DynamoDB and AWS CLI, today I just got told by the offshore team that I am not supposed to use Access and Secret keys **at all** that I'm supposed to use IAM roles and I have been researching how to do that but I'm stuck, has anyone here ever had the same issue?

Comment: This is very unclear.  Is this in a local environment?  On an EC2?  Somewhere else?  What are you stuck on?

Comment: @stdunbar Backend(REST API) is hosted in AWS BeanStalk, Frontend(React app) is hosted in AWS S3 as a static web page, and AWS CLI is running in local machines

Answer (score 0):

If everything was done the way you said it in the question and also in your comment reply to @stdunbar, it is **impossible** to do so, those are the purpose of both secret and access keys, i dont think your offshore team knows what they are talking about

Answer (score 0):

There are methods to acquire STS session keys (like when you assume a role) from AWS. One solution is Hashicorp Vault, but this requires the infrastructure has been configured to allow this. There are other methods that use the webui session to generate an STS token.

Ask your offshore team what method you should use to get a role based access session token. You were probably used to the cli asking for Access Key ID and Secret Key.  The session key will come in three parts instead of two. The session access key id will start with ASIA instead of AKIA; the session secret access key is the same as its static counterpart; the session token is a very long string.

The easiest way to set these are to edit the credentials file in .aws/credentials. If you use `aws configure` you won't be prompted to set the session token. you could use `aws configure set` for each of the parts, if you don't already have profiles set up in your credential file you can just edit the default credential profile.

source:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The point that they're (correctly) making is that your application should not include explicit credentials.

Instead, the application should be configured in Elastic Beanstalk with an IAM role. When the application runs and uses an AWS SDK, the SDK will be able to retrieve temporary credentials from the Beanstalk environment that it is running on.

You can read more at [Managing Elastic Beanstalk Instance Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html).